# Conditionally rolling up dates in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I am trying to work out a way to conditionally roll up dates in R.

Suppose I have the following table below and I want to roll dates up using the Flags variable. The Flag can either be 1 or 2 and dictates which subsequent dates can be linked up.

```
DateStart <- c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-12", "2018-01-20")
DateEnd <- c("2018-01-05", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-12", "2018-01-15", "2018-01-20", "2018-01-21")
IndexRecord <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
Flag1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
Flag2 <- c(2,1,1,1,1,1)
Flag3 <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1)


df1 <- data.frame(DateStart = as.Date(DateStart), 
                  DateEnd = as.Date(DateEnd), 
                  IndexRecord = IndexRecord,
                  Flag1 = Flag1,
                  Flag2 = Flag2,
                  Flag3 = Flag3) %>% 
  arrange(DateStart)

df1

|   | DateStart  | DateEnd    | IndexRecord | Flag1 | Flag2 | Flag3 |
|---|------------|------------|-------------|-------|-------|-------|
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-05 | 1           | 1     | 2     | 1     |
| 2 | 2018-01-04 | 2018-01-09 | NA          | 1     | 1     | 1     |
| 3 | 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-12 | NA          | 1     | 1     | 2     |
| 4 | 2018-01-09 | 2018-01-15 | NA          | 1     | 1     | 1     |
| 5 | 2018-01-12 | 2018-01-20 | NA          | 1     | 1     | 2     |
| 6 | 2018-01-20 | 2018-01-21 | NA          | 1     | 1     | 1     |
```

A Flag with value of 1 for the current period means that for a subsequent row to have a valid link, the subsequent row must have DateStart **occurring before** DateEnd of the current row. Using Flag1 as the column of interest, the result would look like:

```
|   | DateStart  | DateEnd    | IndexRecord | Flag1 | 
|---|------------|------------|-------------|-------|
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-05 | 1           | 1     | 
| 2 | 2018-01-04 | 2018-01-09 | NA          | 1     | 
| 3 | 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-12 | NA          | 1     |
| 4 | 2018-01-09 | 2018-01-15 | NA          | 1     | 
| 5 | 2018-01-12 | 2018-01-20 | NA          | 1     |
```

A Flag with value of 2 for the current period means that for a subsequent row to have a valid link, the subsequent row must have DateStart **occurring on** the DateEnd of the current row. Using Flag2 as the column of interest, the result would look like:

```
|   | DateStart  | DateEnd    | IndexRecord | Flag2 | 
|---|------------|------------|-------------|-------|
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-05 | 1           | 2     |
| 3 | 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-12 | NA          | 1     |
| 4 | 2018-01-09 | 2018-01-15 | NA          | 1     |
| 5 | 2018-01-12 | 2018-01-20 | NA          | 1     |
```

One of the more complex cases could occur with patterns such as seen in Flag3 with the desired results:

```
|   | DateStart  | DateEnd    | IndexRecord | Flag3 |
|---|------------|------------|-------------|-------|
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-05 | 1           | 1     |
| 2 | 2018-01-04 | 2018-01-09 | NA          | 1     |
| 3 | 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-12 | NA          | 2     |
| 5 | 2018-01-12 | 2018-01-20 | NA          | 2     |
| 6 | 2018-01-20 | 2018-01-21 | NA          | 1     |
```

Cheers,

J

Edits:
Since this was perhaps not clear let me clarify step by step.

Flag1.

1. We see that in Row 1 it ends on the 2018-01-05 and Flag1 is 1.
2. This means that for a subsequent row to be linked to this episode, the next episode's DateStart must occur before DateEnd of Row 1. Row 2, satisfies this condition since 2018-01-04 occurs before 2018-01-05 and therefore is valid link.
3. If we look at the remaining rows, all these dates are nested except the Row 6. Since Flag1 of Row5 is 1, we cannot count Row 6, hence why the table stops at Row 5.
4. Total elapsed time is the from 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-20.

Flag2.

1. Row 1 has Flag2 equal to 2 which means that only a subsequent DateStart of 2018-01-05 can be linked to this row. Therefore Row 2 is dropped. If we keeping moving down we see that Row 3 has a DateStart of 2018-01-05 and therefore can be linked to Row 1.
2. Looking at the remaining rows, it has the same pattern as for Flag1 since Flag1 and Flag2 are identical from this point onwards.
3. Similarly to Flag1, total elapsed time is the from 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-20
4. There is no difference in elapsed time compared to Flag1 but differs in the journey taken.

Flag3.

1. Flag3 for Row 1 and Row 2 are the same as in Flag1 which means at this point Row 1, Row 2, and Row 3 are kept as in the Flag1 example.
2. Flag3 for Row 3 however is 2. Since the DateEnd of Row 3 is 2018-01-12, only Row 5 can be linked and Row 4 is removed.
3. Since Row 5 has Flag3 of 2 and a DateEnd of 2018-01-20, Row 6 can also be linked to this set.
4. The total elapsed time for this set is from 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-21.

Comment: I was probably not clear. My expected outputs are the last three tables if I were to run the same functions for Flag1, Flag2, and Flag3 separately.

Comment: Is there an error in youur first table? The start date of row 2 is before end date of row 1.

Comment: This is not a mistake and is considered as a nested case. Dates can overlap one another.

Comment: man, I read that three times and I still don't get it. I think there is a mistake : with flag 1, DateStart must occurrs before DateEnd, and not after. Because if not, your examples make no sense

Comment: @denis I've added additional comments. Please let me know if it still does not make sense.

Comment: @JT1 so I was right, it is `A Flag with value of 1 for the current period means that for a subsequent row to have a valid link, the subsequent row must have DateStart occurring before DateEnd `, and not `after` ? I correct it